# How to line up images horizontally and center with css when using a premade javascript magnifying glass?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on placing a javascript magnifying glass on site.

I need help positioning the images in a straight horizontal line, right next to each other, with no white space in between. Setup must also be centered in middle of page.

Like this: http://s17.postimg.org/6nwizreov/Screenshot.png

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/NightSpark/dtsqcpv8/

(The two js files and css are from magnifier.js, by Mark Rolich)

Thanks

```css
.magnifier-thumb-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}

.magnifier-lens {
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden
}

.magnifier-loader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background: transparent;
    background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
    z-index: 1000;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F323232,endColorstr=#7F323232)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7F323232,endColorstr=#7F323232)
}

.magnifier-loader-text {
    font: 13px Arial;
    margin-top: 10px
}

.magnifier-large {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100
}

.magnifier-preview {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden
}

.magnifier-preview img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}

.opaque {
    opacity: .5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)
}

.hidden {
    display: none
}
```

Comment: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dtsqcpv8/1/) like this

Comment: Great, but how do you center the piece in the middle of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/dtsqcpv8/2/

adding this you can `center` it replace `body` with the parent of the element

```
body{
    text-align:center;
}
.cont{
    display:inline-block;
}
```